# XPath - Locate node using its flattened descendant text

Tags: xpath, selenium

I got this html :

```
<tr>
   <td>
       Some
       <strong>
           text
       </strong>
       <em>
           and more
       </em>
   </td>
   ...
</tr>
```

I need to locate my `td` element with this text `Some text and more`. I know that I can get this text with this XPath expression :

```
//td//text()
```

But I can not find a solution to locate `td` element. I try this :

```
//td[//text()='Some text and more']
```

but I get errors. Do you know a working XPath expression for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, XPath uses forward slashes, never backslashes.

Secondly, I believe this may be the XPath you need:

```
//td[normalize-space(.) = 'Some text and more']
```

Could you give that a try?